# Why is the binary of clang-10 so large (123MB)?

Tags: clang, llvm

Clang 10 has been released. I downloaded the [source](https://releases.llvm.org/) and build it myself as follows:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 ../llvm

make -j16

make install
```

The resulting binary of clang is located at `/usr/local/bin/clang-10`, and its size is horriably **123MB**!

If I install the clang-9 by `dnf install clang`, the binary size of clang-9 is just **201KB**!

Any wrong steps?

Comment: static build vs dynamic build? I doubt that clang9 features are shoehorned in 201kb

Comment: Try with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON`. I have a debug build of clang-11 currently. Its 6 MB.

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/bin/clang-10` say?  In particular, is it stripped?

Comment: Sounds as if you've accidentally built a static clang executable with support for cross-compiling to every supported target platform. You probably want to reconfigure cmake so you build only to the target platforms that correspond to your host.

Comment: Your `clang-10` binary likely includes LLVM linked in statically and/or is built with symbols included. Note that the 201KB of dnf is misleading. The `clang9.0-libs` package exists in Fedora and likely contains most of the heavy stuff, plus the other similarly named packages and LLVM.